# Fetch backend translations in webpack

Tags: laravel, vue.js, translation

I'm creating a `laravel/vuejs` project, and I really want to have all my translation files in just a single place - in the backend. Then I want to fetch them in webpack while I build my frontend, and use them from there.

There happens to be many issues though - laravel can only use `.php` extension, because the keys in `.json` files apparently cannot be nested.

I really don't want to pass all my keys through the `window` object, and I want to avoid using external libraries. What's the recommended way to do it in laravel projects?

Comment: have you already made this in php? all your front end is in Vuejs or mixied with blade?

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own service which generates a javscript object or json in a js file and load it via webpack then make it available to you vueJs.

I personaly use this package [package](https://github.com/martinlindhe/laravel-vue-i18n-generator) which handle the generation of javascript file on the Laravel side and gives you all the helpers you need on the vueJs side too. Their may be limitation depending on your needs thow so be sure to check the doc

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to load your translation files via an API call on load of your Vue application. Another option would be to pass the translations files' array (json encoded) directly to a prop in your Vue application.